# How can I put labels in two charts using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, histogram

I'm trying to plot two histogram using the result of a group by. But the labels just appear in one of the labels.
How can I put the label in both charts?
And how can I put different title for the charts (e.g. first as Men's grade and Second as Woman's grade)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

microdataEnem = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\Data Science\\Data Analysis\\Projects\\ENEM\\DADOS\\MICRODADOS_ENEM_2019.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', nrows=10000)

sex_essaygrade = ['TP_SEXO', 'NU_NOTA_REDACAO']

filter_sex_essaygrade = microdataEnem.filter(items = sex_essaygrade)

filter_sex_essaygrade.dropna(subset = ['NU_NOTA_REDACAO'], inplace = True)
       
filter_sex_essaygrade.groupby('TP_SEXO').hist()
plt.xlabel('Grade')
plt.ylabel('Number of students')


plt.show()
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWalb.png]

Comment: Are you sure the dataframe `filter_sex_essaygrade` that you are passing to the groupby is correct? Both histograms look exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `filter_sex_essaygrade.groupby('TP_SEXO').hist()` you can try the following format: `axs = filter_sex_essaygrade['NU_NOTA_REDACAO'].hist(by=filter_sex_essaygrade['TP_SEXO'])`. This will automatically title each histogram with the group name.

You'll want to set an the variable `axs` equal to this histogram object so that you can modify the x and y labels for both plots.

I created some data similar to yours, and I get the following result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)

sex_essaygrade = ['TP_SEXO', 'NU_NOTA_REDACAO']

## create two distinct sets of grades
sample_grades = np.concatenate((np.random.randint(low=70,high=100,size=100), np.random.randint(low=80,high=100,size=100)))

filter_sex_essaygrade = pd.DataFrame({
    'NU_NOTA_REDACAO': sample_grades,
    'TP_SEXO': ['Men']*100 + ['Women']*100
})
       
axs = filter_sex_essaygrade['NU_NOTA_REDACAO'].hist(by=filter_sex_essaygrade['TP_SEXO'])
for ax in axs.flatten():
    ax.set_xlabel("Grade")
    ax.set_ylabel("Number of students")

plt.show()
```

[image]